# Show multiple values for a field in gridview

Tags: gridview, yii2, yii2-basic-app

i am new in yii2. I have a `languages` master table (in `name` field contains html,css, java,php...) and a `registration` table in which there is a field called `language_id`. I have inserted multiple values for that field using json_encode.
Now in database showing language id's as `["1","2","3","4","5"]`

Now i want to display the data stored in db using a gridview. How can i show the multiple values for languages in gridview. Given below is what i have tried with my **gridview**

```
<?= GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'filterModel' => $searchModel,
        'columns' => [
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

            'first_name',
            'last_name',
            'gender',
            'address',
            ['label'=>'Course',
            'value'=>'course.name'],
            'email:email',
            ['label'=>'Languages Known',
            'value'=>'languages.name'],
            'course_completion_date',

            ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
        ],
    ]); ?>
```

and in my **Model** code is as follows

```
public function getLanguages(){

        $result = json_decode($this->language_id, true);

        return $this->hasOne(Languages::className(), ['id' => $result]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got answer. but I do not think this is the proper solution for this problem. Pagination is not working (when i enter into 2 page and so on) and showing error as :

> `Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`

```
<?= GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'filterModel' => $searchModel,
        'columns' => [
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
            'gender',
            'address',
            ['label'=>'Course',
            'value'=>'course.name'],
            'email:email',
            ['label'=>'Languages Known',
            'value' => function ($data) 
            {
                 $arr= json_decode($data->language_id,true);
                 $lang="";
                 $i=0;
                 foreach ($arr as $value)
                 {
                     $model_lan = Languages::find()->where(['id'=>$value])->one();
                     $lang .= $model_lan->name.' ';
                 }
                 return $lang;
            },],
            'course_completion_date',
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],],
    ]); ?>
```